# Tangent and normal vectors for parameterization of a straight line.

Tags: differential-geometry

Hi everyone just a simple question.

Suppose the curve

$$r(t) = (x_0, t)\\  0 \leq t \leq 1  $$

$x_0$ is some real number.

We see that the unit tangent $T(t)= (0,1) = \dfrac{r'(t)}{\|r'(t)\|} $

Similarly we show that $N(t)=(0,0) = \dfrac{T'(t)}{\|T'(t)\|}$

So my question is the following. Looking at this curve, I agree with the tangent vector. I'm curious with regards to this normal vector however. I believe $N(t) = c(1,0)$, where c is a real number is always normal to the tagent vector, and thus the curve itself. We see in the case when $c=0$, we get the unit normal vector which we get from differential geometry, but there are a ton more which are non trivial. What am I missing here, if anything? It seems to me that the normal vector to this curve, which is oriented correctly is the vector $(-1,0)$.

EDIT: Just noticed this pesky denominator is zero for the unit normal vector, of course the zero vector cannot have length 1, duh..... still some insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? $N(t)=c(1,0)$ is a normal, except when $c=0$. The formula $T(t)=r'(t)/\|r'(t)\|$ is only valid when $r'(t)\ne0$. It follows that, in general, $N(t)$ is not well defined when the curve is a straight line. But the specific example you chose happens to be an exception to this, because in two dimensions it is defined (up to a sign)!  In any case, how did you get $T'(t)/\|T'(t)\|=(0,0)$?

Comment: Hi, I know, I mentioned that in my edit. I guess I'm curious why the math breaks down for such a simple example? Is it just bad to use this math for this set of curves?